# Not able to add rows to table on click on asp.net button

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to add rows to a table on click of asp.net button, but while trying to add same values at multiple rows, it is just displaying just one row.

```
 Table1.Rows.AddAt(index:=0, row:=row_)
 Table1.Rows.AddAt(index:=1, row:=row_)
 Table1.Rows.AddAt(index:=2, row:=row_)
 MsgBox(Table1.Rows.Count)
```

Here row_ is a TableRow object.
It is just displaying one row instead of 3.
And the value of Table1.Rows.Count is 3.

Comment: If I try to add different row values, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the table row object before adding it at that index.

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
```

Then you can Add it at the desired index in the table:

```
Table1.Rows.AddAt(0, row)
```

Or try to Create a new row and add it to your table control

```
   TableRow row = new TableRow();

   table.Rows.Add(row);
   table.Rows.Add(row);
   table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: I am doing so, still it is not helping

Comment: What if you simply try to add a new row or as many rows as you want displayed then use the Rows.Insert( )?

Comment: Dim row_ As TableRow        Dim cellModel As TableCell         row_ = New TableRow           cellModel = New TableCell           cellModel.Text = serial_no.Text         row_.Cells.Add(cellModel) 
             Table1.Rows.AddAt(index:=0, row:=row_) 
                Table1.Rows.AddAt(index:=1, row:=row_) 
                 Table1.Rows.AddAt(index:=2, row:=row_)

Comment: I am not able to find method AddRow()

Comment: try Rows.Add();

Comment: Rows.Add() asks for a parameter of type TableRow

Comment: Also there is no method table.Rows.Insert()

Comment: Add the row Control in the parentheses

Comment: Adding row in Rows.Add(row_), this again prints one row

Comment: Will it let you put a int inside the parentheses like so Rows.Add(3)? This should add three new rows to your control